# Large Reports for MSRS

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005, ssrs-2008

I have a report that needs to be able to render a very large amount of pages (about 4500 in this instance) in a web browser.  The total time needed to finish on the report server from start time to end time is about 30 mins for the instance that I am looking at.  Does anyone know what options exist for handling the rendering of such a large report in a web browser?

In terms of looking into how this can be resolved I have already performed the following tasks.  The report gets its data off of a database table that already has the data flattened to the point that the TimeDataRetrieval on the report server is 17812 or about 18 secs.  The report itself has been reformatted to include the least expensive report objects that it can in order to render the data in the correct format.  I basically consists of a table with about 4 nested tables and thats it.  We were trying to accomplish this on a 2005 report server but continued to run into memory issues that were not feasible for our clients.  In response to that we moved this onto a 2008 report server to take advantage of the fact that it uses the file system instead of memory and finally were able to get this to work without running out of the available memory but of course it takes much longer.

Answer (score 2):

I would say this is impossible, a browser is not ment to handle that amount of data. I find it hard to believe anyone is finding a 4500 page report useful though.

If that data is in approximately the same format for all the pages you should split this up into a master-subreport style report. Have a main report of a couple of pages full of links to the other subreports.

Comment: I agree. You optimise a 4500 page report by making it smaller and meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create the report on the disk as HTML
2. Each of the 4500 pages is a single HTML page
3. Link from your GUI to the reports page + give an index to each and every of the 4500 pages on the disk

Comment: Do you know if there is a white paper or something that explains how to accomplish something like this using MSRS?  I'm not familiar with this process.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, and it sounds like you might not have used reporting services before.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the task manager, generate your report during the night, so the user just have to download it, the render have already been done.